# Buttons with :before sprite overlapping and not resizing to fit text only when parent overflows

Tags: html, css

This only happens when the elements don't fit the page/container at run time.

Example 1 - I have forced a div to scroll with fixed height/width

Example 2 - If browser window is too small to accommodate, they will overlap

Example 3 - No overlap

If I remove the following css block, the issues go away. Any ideas?

```
/* CSS3 BUTTON ICON METHOD, DOESN'T SUPPORT IE7 */
*[class*="icon-"]:before {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/NwDXbMb.png");
content: "";
height: 16px;
width: 16px;

display: block;
float: left;

vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 6px;

/*position:relative;*/
/*background-attachment: scroll;*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 128px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weaponx86/sHnHn/

Full screen example:
http://jsfiddle.net/weaponx86/sHnHn/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the :before selector to "inline-block" and get rid of the float:left.

```
/* CSS3 BUTTON ICON METHOD, DOESN'T SUPPORT IE7 */
*[class*="icon-"]:before /*,.icon:before*/ {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/NwDXbMb.png");

padding:0;

content: "";
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display: inline-block;

vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 6px;
text-indent:16px;
/*position:relative;*/
/*background-attachment: scroll;*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 128px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weaponx86/sHnHn/7/